nextjs import multiple components from index manifest imports everything
BACKGROUND:
I have a project where I have all my UI components in a /components directory.
Right now I export each component in its own file as:
export function Component1() { ... } 

and import them individually into my page as such:
import { Component1 } from "@/components/Component1";
import { Component2 } from "@/components/Component2";

I would like to be able to import multiple components at once, like this:
import { Component1, Component2 } from "../components";

So I created this index/manifest file:
/components/index.js
import { Component1} from './Component1';
import { Component2} from './Component2';

export { Component1, Component1 }

THE ISSUE:
The issue is that when I try to import them using this syntax:
import { Component1, Component2 } from "../components";

It seems to be importing ALL the components at once because I noticed a significant slow down my compiled index.js chunk went from 169kb to 6MB.

You have multiple options to do this;

option one

export { Component1 } from './Component1';
export { Component2 } from './Component2';
// ... and so on for other components


option two

export * from './Component1';
export * from './Component2';
// ... and so on for other components


Thank you for your suggestions. I removed the import statements from my index.js manifest file and used option 1 as you described. However, the issue with importing everything still happens despite the fact I am trying to import only two of those components into my page.
